# Allow typeahead,js to autocomplete words in text, instead of just single values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I want to use typeahead.js to auto-complete words in textarea. My textarea is to write a text. So I have a source of words, which should be used by typeahead to suggest user on every entry of new word.

I tried to get current value and destroy typeahead and reinitialize it and set previous value, but it did not work, it seems this is not correct way.

Please help me to find a solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/ to be what I was looking for.